# Find a matrix that ranks another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having this matrix A:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

How do I find a matrix that ranks this matrix? basically I need to find a matrix B such that exist 
AB = 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        0 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        0 & 0 & 11 & 12 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

How can I find such a matrix? I wanna know how to do it by myself, it just seems too complicated using equations, I've tried manipulating the identity matrix in order to give me these results but didn't succeed, maybe I'm just in the wrong direction.

Thanks

Comment: You need to perform **column** operations in order to get the second matrix. Since you want to do it by yourself i give you [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) link, which i think is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the column $(1,0,0)^T$ out of multiplying anything on the right of $A$, because all of the columns of $A$ satisfy $x-2y+z=0$ (and so will any linear combination of them) but $(1,0,0)^T$ doesn't.